# Programming menus into TableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was curious about the following two images:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Are they using programmatically created tableview cells to create these menus? I’m a bit new to Swift and was trying to recreate them for practice and realized quickly that I don’t think I have the appropriate name/description for researching them and guides in order to tinker around with.

Comment: Look into [viewForHeaderInSection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview)

Comment: Those a standard `UITableView` with "grouped" style (versus "plain").

Comment: @RaziTiwana Why?

Comment: @rmaddy i assumed  reading this `order to tinker around with` that this would give the OP more Flexibility but re-reading the Question `grouped style` is enough here, honest mistake.

Comment: These are the default tableView cells. The default ones have image on the left, a title label and a description label, as well as an accessory view (right arrow). If you need more customization, then you would go for a custom tableView cell.